# With C++, how do I wrap a vector and overload [] for all types?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Long story short, I have

```
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class wrapped_vector {
private:
        std::vector<T> elements;
public:
        wrapped_vector() {
                elements.resize(20);
        }

        T& operator[](int i) {
                return elements[i];
        }

        const T& operator[](int i) const {
                return elements[i];
        }
};

int main(void) {
        wrapped_vector<int> test_int;
        test_int[0] = 1;

        wrapped_vector<bool> test_bool;
        test_bool[0] = true; // remove this line and it all compiles
}
```

and it gives me the compile error

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘T& wrapped_vector<T>::operator[](int) [with T = bool]’:
test.cpp:28:13:   required from here
test.cpp:15:34: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘bool&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::vector<bool, std::allocator<bool> >::reference {aka std::_Bit_reference}’
```

Comment: Can I guess it has to do with it being a `vector<bool>`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You got bitten by yet another side-effect of the "magic" `std::vector<bool>`.

Since `std::vector<bool>` doesn't actually store a contiguous array of `bool`s, but packs them as a bitset, it cannot return a "real" reference to a bit in the middle of the bitset (since bits aren't directly addressable); for this reason, its `operator[]` returns a proxy object that, overloading its `operator=`, "fakes" a reference semantic.

The problem lies here: this proxy object *is not* a `bool &`, so you cannot return it as such in your method.

The simplest way to solve would be something like this:

```
    typename std::vector<T>::reference operator[](int i) {
            return elements[i];
    }

    typename std::vector<T>::const_reference operator[](int i) const {
            return elements[i];
    }
```

that guarantees that you actually return whatever type `std::vector` uses as "reference to `T`" in its methods.

Also, you may want to use `std::vector<T>::size_type` for indexes (mostly for coherency of your forwarder functions than anything else).

Comment: Great answer, thank you! Forgive me for asking, but regarding your last point: Replacing int with your suggestion for indexes, I get "error: ‘std::vector<T, std::allocator<_Tp1> >::size_type’ is not a type". What am I doing wrong_

Comment: @ChristianJonassen Try adding "typename" before it since it's a dependent type.

Comment: Did you forget a typename? Since it's a dependent name, it should be `typename std::vector<T>::size_type` (you may want to make it a `typedef` for it).

Comment: Indeed, sorry. However, making it typename std::vector<T>::reference operator[](typename std::vector<T>::size_type i) gives me a warning.

Comment: @ChristianJonassen: what warning?

Comment: Oh well, adding it for both simultaneously seemed to work. Herp derp. Thanks again. ^^